# Failed to create directory error when running dropbox uploader script on raspberry pi

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi3, dropbox

I'm creating an python script that automates uploading images from a usb stick to dropbox. This activates when you hit a button on Pin 29. When I run the dropbox_uploader (https://www.raspberrypi.org/magpi/dropbox-raspberry-pi/) in the terminal it works fine, but when I translate it to python it fails to create a new directory.

I've tried finding working around os.system() as I feel that's the problem, but nothing so far has worked.

```
from time import sleep
import os
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO


GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
button=29
GPIO.setup(button,GPIO.IN,pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)

command = 'Dropbox-Uploader/dropbox_uploader.sh upload /media/pi/TOSHIBA_EXT/TESTBOX X'

while(1):
    if GPIO.input(button)==0:
        print "Button pressed and starting upload"
        os.system(command)
```

Hit a button and the script runs. Sends images to dropbox.

Answer (score 0):

OK! Well...I tried the code on a different wifi network...and it works...not sure why, but yay!  :)